# fix Possible null pointer dereference

Tags: java, findbugs

I have the following codes but fails when using findbugs.

```
    protected void writeStream(final InputStream inputStream, final Path destinationFile) throws IOException {
    final Path parentDirectory = destinationFile.getParent();
    Path tempFile = null;
    try {
        // Create the temporary dir for temporary download
        Files.createDirectories(getTempDownloadPath());
        Files.createDirectories(parentDirectory);
        // Create the temporary file in the temporary dir
        tempFile = Files.createTempFile(getTempDownloadPath(), destinationFile.getFileName().toString(), ".tmp");
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Files.copy(inputStream, tempFile, REPLACE_EXISTING);
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Files.move(tempFile, destinationFile, ATOMIC_MOVE, REPLACE_EXISTING);
        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        log.error("Failed to write file.", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        try {
            if (tempFile != null) {
                Files.deleteIfExists(tempFile);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn("Failed to delete file: " + tempFile, e);
        }
    }
}
```

It is complaining that

```
tempFile = Files.createTempFile(getTempDownloadPath(), destinationFile.getFileName().toString(), ".tmp");
```

**Possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method**

Which part is wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: `Path`'s `getFileName()` method can return null.

Comment: even I add a particular check at the very beginning to check `destinationFile!=null`, it still fails.

Comment: But that's not what he said.

Comment: maybe because destinationFile is not null, but destinationFile.getFileName() can return null and you call toString() on it

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Well, I am not sure why some ppl down-vote this question, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Files.createTempFile does not return a Path object, but a string.